# Los botones Agregar etiqueta favorita y etiqueta ignorada se ven cortados

Tags: bug, estado-completado

En la barra de la derecha en la sección **Etiquetas favoritas** y **Etiquetas ignoradas** el botón <kbd>Agregar</kbd> se ve cortado, no entra en el espacio, seguramente porque en inglés la palabra *Add* es mas corta.

[image: bug]

Se debería hacer más ancho este botón para que se vea correctamente o de no ser posible tal vez cambiar la palabra por un <kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: el sitio en portuges tiene el mismo problema. Para mejorar el soporte de internacionalizacion, deberia modificarse el estilo del textbox a la izquierda del boton, para que se ajuste al tamaño del boton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que ya ha sido corregido.

[image: Editar etiquetas favoritas]

Answer (score 0):

Para mi se ve bien el espacio...

[image]

Comment: Prueba Chrome. Además en esa imagen también esta un poco cortado

Comment: La prueba se hizo en Chrome...hmm.

Comment: También uso Chrome (de hecho, Chromium, en Debian Linux), y tengo el problema.